# The probability that the party $2$ will be in power after the next two elections,given that the party $1$ is in power,is

Tags: probability

There are three main political parties namely $1,2,3$.If $p_{ij}$denote the probability that the party $j$ wins the general elections contested when party $i$ is in the power.The probability that the party $2$ will be in power after the next two elections,given that the party $1$ is in power,is 
$(A)0.27\hspace{1cm}(B)0.24\hspace{1cm}(C)0.14\hspace{1cm}(D)0.06$
$p_{11}=0.7,p_{12}=0.2,p_{13}=0.1,p_{21}=0.5,p_{22}=0.3,p_{23}=0.2,p_{31}=0.3,p_{32}=0.4,p_{33}=0.3$

I suspect,Bayes should be applied here.But since this is asking probability after next two elections,i am confused how to handle this question.Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer B is correct**

*If we assume that the chance winning the actual election depend only on the actual party in power and not on the previous results of elections then
we are talking about a Markov chain with the following state transition matrix*:

$$
\mathbb P=\begin{bmatrix}
p_{11}&p_{12}&p_{13}\\
p_{21}&p_{22}&p_{23}\\
p_{31}&p_{32}&p_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0.7&0.2&0.1\\
0.5&0.3&0.2\\
0.3&0.4&0.3
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Here $$p_{ij}=P(\text{ party } j \text{ wins } \mid \text{ party } i \text{ in power}).$$

*If we don't assume this independence from the past then the problem cannot be solved based on the data given.*

The state transition probabilities considering two elections is $\mathbb P^2$.

$$\mathbb P^2
=\begin{bmatrix}
0.7&0.2&0.1\\
0.5&0.3&0.2\\
0.3&0.4&0.3
\end{bmatrix}^2
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0.62&\color{red}{0.24}&0.14\\
0.56&0.27&0.17\\
0.5&0.3&0.2
\end{bmatrix}
.$$

The second element of the first row ($0.24$ / answer **B**) tells the probability that party $2$ will be in power after the second election from now assuming that party $1$ is in power today.

---

**Elementary solution**

Let $P_0^i, P_1^i, P_2^i$ denote that party $i$ is in power today, after the next election, and after the second election from now, respectively.

The question is the value of the following conditional probability:

$$P(P_2^2\mid P_0^1)=\frac{P(P_2^2\cap P_0^1)}{P(P_0^1)} \tag 1.$$

Obviously

$$P(P_2^2\cap P_0^1)=P(P_2^2\cap P_1^1\cap P_0^1)+P(P_2^2\cap P_1^2\cap P_0^1)+P(P_2^2\cap P_1^3\cap P_0^1)=$$

$$P(P_2^2\mid P_1^1\cap P_0^1)P(P_1^1\cap P_0^1)+P(P_2^2\mid P_1^2\cap P_0^1)P(P_1^2\cap P_0^1)+P(P_2^2\mid P_1^3\cap P_0^1)P(P_1^3\cap P_0^1)=$$

$$=P(P_2^2\mid P_1^1)P(P_1^1\cap P_0^1)+P(P_2^2\mid P_1^2)P(P_1^2\cap P_0^1)+P(P_2^2\mid P_1^3)P(P_1^3\cap P_0^1)=$$

$$=P(P_2^2\mid P_1^1)P(P_1^1\mid P_0^1)P(P_0^1)+P(P_2^2\mid P_1^2)P(P_1^1\mid P_0^1)P(P_0^1)+P(P_2^2\mid P_1^3)P(P_1^3\mid P_0^1)P(P_0^1).$$

We used the fact the the result of the election depends only on the current government (and *perhaps* on the abilities of the competing parties).

$P(P_0^1)$ cancels out in $(1)$, so we have now

$$P(P_2^2\mid P_0^1)=$$
$$=P(P_2^2\mid P_1^1)P(P_1^1\mid P_0^1)+P(P_2^2\mid P_1^2)P(P_1^1\mid P_0^1)+P(P_2^2\mid P_1^3)P(P_1^3\mid P_0^1)=$$
$$=p_{12}p_{11}+p_{22}p_{12}+p_{32}p_{13}=$$
$$=0.2\cdot0.7+0.3\cdot0.2+0.4\cdot0.1=\color{red}{0.24}.$$